# Command \@parboxrestore has changed

Tags: packages, csquotes, lineno

I am working on a college project and to be specific we are using Another's template in Overleaf. so I don't know that much about LaTeX or Overleaf. There is an error showing up:

> /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
> Command @parboxrestore has changed.

I read about the posts about this problem, they are saying to place `\usepackage{csquotes}` before using package `lineno`. Now the problem is that there is no line like `\usepackage{csquotes}` in `main.tex`.

The packages are:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}  
 
 
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]











\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=2cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfigure}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}





\nprounddigits{3}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\setstackEOL{\#}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}


%\usepackage{subcaption} %incompatible with subfig
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' v
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the `Thesis` class available?

Comment: Thank you sir I got it

Answer (score 6):

I placed `\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}` **before** `\usepackage{csquotes}` and the error message disappeared, exactly the opposite of what was suggested by the references looked at by the OP.